# Boiling points of HF, HCl, HI

Tags: hydrogen-bond, melting-point

I'm really confused over how to weigh the molecular mass with intermolecular forces such as hydrogen bonding in HF in terms of figuring out the melting points in relation to each other.

I know that HF has the highest melting point out of HCl and HI, but then HCl and HI both have significantly larger molecular mass.

So how does one properly explain why HF has the higher melting point out of HCl and HI? (Not just saying that generally hydrogen bonds out weigh the molecular mass when considering boiling point)

Is there any mathematical basis?

Comment: You seem to be asking about one/both/either/neither of melting points and boiling points. Please clarify by editing the post.

Answer (score 1):

In HF there is a hydrogen bond which always outweighs all other factors when deciding properties related to stability. H-Bonded molecules are very stable

Comment: Is there no mathematical basis for this? Surely there's some explanation using mathematics other than actual data.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by a mathematical basis. Could you give an example of what you mean by explaining sthg in chem on a mathematical basis?

Comment: Is there a quantifiable reason why hydrogen bonds outweigh the other factors?